# create drop down to view month and year in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this function to create a dropdown for months and year my problem is am getting an error like below:

> Unknown column 'format' in 'where clause'

below is the code anyone help to get rid of this error

```
date_condition = ' and 1=1 ';
if($date_type==1)
{

    $date_condition = ' and m.submittimestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 300 DAY) AND NOW() ';
}
else if($date_type==2)
{
    $date_condition = ' and YEAR(m.submittimestamp) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and MONTH(m.submittimestamp)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ';  
}
else if($date_type==3)
{
    $date_condition = ' and YEAR(m.submittimestamp) = YEAR(date(format)) AND MONTH(m.submittimestamp)=MONTH(date) ';    
}
```

conditions 1 and 2 are working perfectly but condition 3 is getting error

Below is the code for drop down and script

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <input name="filter_options" 
        <?php echo $option3; ?>  
        value="3" onchange="toggleDate(1)" type="radio" class="form-control" id="from_date">
    <label for="from_date">show status for the month of </label>
    <select name="month" class="form-control">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i) {
            $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d months', $i));
            $value = date('m', $time);
            $label = date('F ', $time);
            printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="year" class="form-control">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i) {
            $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
            $value = date('Y', $time);
            $label = date('Y ', $time);
            printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
        }
        ?>
        <option value=" ">year</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you everything you need to know, you have a syntax error. Remove the letter "e" at the beginning of the code noted in your error.

```
e) AND MONTH(m.submittimestamp)=MONTH(date) GROUP
```

should be

```
) AND MONTH(m.submittimestamp)=MONTH(date) GROUP
```

Comment: i am getting error like this Unknown column 'format' in 'where clause'